# Problems with heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm having problems with running my application on Heroku. It always shows me this error:

https://gist.github.com/902104

I think that is an important line here, that is:

```
2011-04-04T10:50:59-07:00 app[web.1]: /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': /app/app/models/gallery.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND (SyntaxError)
```

But my gallery.rb file is ok, here it is:

```
class Gallery < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many :gallery_photos
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :gallery_photos    
 belongs_to :content

end
```

So what's going wrong?

Update: here is the warnings of the git push heroku:

warning: You did not specify any refspecs to push, and the current remote

warning: has not configured any push refspecs. The default action in this

warning: case is to push all matching refspecs, that is, all branches

warning: that exist both locally and remotely will be updated.  This may

warning: not necessarily be what you want to happen.

warning:

warning: You can specify what action you want to take in this case, and

warning: avoid seeing this message again, by configuring 'push.default' to:

warning:   'nothing'  : Do not push anything

warning:   'matching' : Push all matching branches (default)

warning:   'tracking' : Push the current branch to whatever it is tracking

warning:   'current'  : Push the current branch

Comment: Did you also check for an error in category.rb?


From your github output:

`/app/app/models/category.rb:22: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting kEND (SyntaxError)`

Comment: Your log show the 5th line of gallery.rb as `belongs_to: :content` here is your problem i think, maybe an update issue ? see first answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make sure that heroku is using the latest code?

1. git status (make sure everything is clean)
2. git push heroku (unless it says "already up to date" you were not on latest)

If that still doesn't fix it, then it's likely a text encoding problem, since the gallery.rb file does look fine, then try to get the code as heroku sees it:

```
git clone -o heroku git@heroku.com:your-app-name.git
```

This will create a directory called heroku -- go in there and examine the category.rb file.

And if that still fails -- go with Heroku support. They'll help find the problem.

Comment: everytime that I try git clone -o heroku git@heroku.com:cec.git it shows me this error:   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.

Comment: what about the git push heroku? Does that fail or succeed?